# Data of Message app in IOS

Tags: ios, sms, message

I am developing a messaging app for IOS. So, for this I want to access and modify messages from the default message app in IOS.

So, how can I access the data of message app like we access photos and contacts?

Thank You

Answer (score 3):

You **Cannot** access messages from the default messages App. This is not privileged for developers by Apple.

For more information check this link :

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SystemMessaging_TopicsForIOS/Articles/SendinganSMSMessage.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010416-SW1